# Can't create a standalone profile for membership card information

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, profile

I'm trying to create a profile page where a user tells us where they want to pick their membership card up. We have the field on new membership applications, but we want to send cards to existing members. Due to the cost of mailing we're going to drop them off at the member's preferred retail partner for pickup.

I have a custom field for the pickup location, and I created a custom profile with that field, plus the first and last name as view-only in order to verify the profile. The intent is to email the user and include their contact hash to ensure their profile appears. I received the following error when trying to preview the profile on the website front-end:

"Profile search, view and edit are not supported for Profiles which include fields for more than one record type."

I then stripped it back to only include the membership card pickup field. I still receive the error.

Is there any way to collect this information? I'd rather not send a bulk email and have to manually update every member's profile.

We are using wordpress 4.3.1 and civi 4.6.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are some of the fields on the profile membership fields? I think the issue here is that Profiles that you can send people to via a checksum will only support Contact fields, not Membership fields, since if the person has more than one Membership there is no way to know which one to update.

Comment: This may be the answer. This custom field is associated with the membership. Is there another way to get around it?

Comment: Sorry not that I know of in WP. In Drupal I would check if the Webform-Civicrm code would cope

Comment: If this answer did provide some value pls +1 or accept since that helps the SE system work well